# Any updated http segmenter for IPad / iPhone video streaming with latest ffmpeg?

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg, ipad-2, mediastreamsegmenter

I would like to know if there are any **http file segmenters** with support for the *latest ffmpeg* libraries?

So far I have found some projects, although I haven't been able to compile them using ffmpeg 0.9

1. http://svn.assembla.com/svn/legend/segmenter/
2. http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fork at github and added support for the latest FFMPEG.

https://github.com/interpegasus/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor